# Does camera calibration negate lens color quality?

Tags: lens

One of the quality of lenses are the way it renders color. Some say, a lens of a certain brand has a special color quality to it etc.

But if you do camera calibration, will it matter at that point? Since the definition of calibration is to standardized all the data.

Comment: You can wreck anything if you try hard enough but the attributes of a lens will to some extent be visible for sensible 'calibration".

Answer (score 2):

If the calibration is done once for the camera and not for every individual lens, then the answer based on my empirical observations would be no. I calibrate every camera I get and still can see differences in color quality.

I suspect that what we call "color" in lenses is actually something more complex, with contrast, ability to reproduce clean blacks etc. in the equation. Calibration does not seem to smear these differences.

Besides, the calibration differences in color are subtle compared to cranking up color temperature or saturation sliders in photo editor.

Answer (score 2):

If the profiling were being done for each lens on a certain camera, then no, a certain lens's color quality wouldn't matter because the profile for that lens would account for it as an "error".

But if only the camera itself is being profiled, the special color quality of a certain lens would remain after processing, because only the camera would be brought to a neutral point in the processing stage.

Answer (score 0):

A lens having certain way of rendering colours will show it differently on different film stock. There are many variables in the process, too.

When it comes to calibration, it is a factory process ensuring the standard response of colour channels. Unless one has access to firmware constants in the camera and calibrated light source together with calibrated neutral density filters he can't change calibration.

What can be (usually) done is changing the colour transform in software. This is usually called profiling (however not all softwares follow ICC standard).

Most often user-end profiling is based on shooting a target with a limited number of approximately known colours (it is a rare case that the profiling target is individually and accurately measured with a lab-grade spectrophotometer) under non-uniform light of unknown quality and with one lens. If the lens is relatively neutral (like instrumental lenses - Nikon in their service manual specify 50/1.4D - or a good macro lens) resulting colour transform is more or less neutral too. However if the lens has some prominent colour qualities, all bets are off.

Profiling a camera without a lens (monochromators are not extremely expensive these days) is a much better approach in all respects.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can help offset it, but if a lens renders colors over a smaller color space, or worse yet, renders two colors the same way, then there isn't a way to fully account for the difference.

The first situation, where the colors are not as vivid when they reach the sensor, will result in a reduced color space as there will be fewer colors able to be recognized.  The sensor itself is only capable of recognizing a certain number of colors and if the lens prevents the brightest or darkest colors from ever being recognized, then you have fewer overall colors available.  This isn't a huge deal, but it does impact image quality slightly.

The second situation is far worse.  If the colors end up looking too close to the same, then it will be impossible to calibrate away from the issue because any calibration adjustment you make to the one will be applied to the other as well.  Thus, you get inaccurate color that can not be fixed.

Color calibration is important for color accuracy, but it will not fully account for inability to transmit colors clearly through a lens without distortion.  There is still a lot of value in a lens that can transmit colors clearly and/or cause a consistent level of distortion that can be corrected for.